# WebStorm gives warning for CSS files using url("/assets/...") path

Tags: css, sass, ide, webstorm

WebStorm gives "Cannot resolve directory 'some_path'" error.
if *assets path* is used instead of *relative path*. By *assets path* I mean path starting with `/assets/`.

[image]

There is no problem when relative path is used:

[image]

Both codes works well in a browser, but for the first one WebStorm gives errors. How to solve this issue or tell WebStorm to ignore it if the path starts with `/assets/`?

Comment: Where is your `/assets/` is located in your project? relative to the project root and website root? Please show it a screenshot of the project View panel that would show this info. The issue quite likely be because the IDE expects that `/assets/` is located in the project root folder (since it starts with `/` (which means absolute path). If it's not (e.g. in a subfolder) then the parent folder must be marked as a Resource Root.

Comment: Yeah you were right. It didn't work in production. It was located relative to the project root.

Answer (score 3):

Have same error. Found solution!
Need to mark src folder as resource root.
To do that: go to webstorm setting->directories select src and click 'Resource root' button.

Comment: The way I do it on PHPStorm is as follows (in case someone wonders about this):
Right click on the root folder of your project, then select "Mark directory as" from the options, and then select "Resource root". The warning should disappear.